# How to use float and double and integer for accurate temperature conversion?

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, double

Please help. I am new to programming. I am focusing on functions now. Basically the function 'sort of' works. However the temperature converted to fahrenheit from celcius is not accurate.Any explanation on why the answers start ok and get more and more wrong would be super helpful. Thanks. Here is the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

//function prototypes
float convertTofahrenheit(float z);

int main (void){
    float x,y;
    int count_c;
    x=convertTofahrenheit(y);

    printf ("%s\t%s","Celcius","Fahrenheit\n");
    for (count_c=0;count_c<=30;count_c++){
        x++;
        printf ("%d\t%f\n", count_c, x);
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

//function for conversion from Celcius to Fahrenheit
float convertTofahrenheit(float z){
    float fahrenheit;
    fahrenheit= ((z*1.8)+32);
    return fahrenheit;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen in that `for` loop?

Comment: Surely this can't be your actual code. `y` is unintialised in the call to `convertTofahrenheit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the conversion inside your loop and pass in count_c converted to a float:

```
float x;  // don't need y
int count_c;

printf ("%s\t%s","Celcius","Fahrenheit\n");
for (count_c=0;count_c<=30;count_c++){
    x=convertTofahrenheit((float)count_c);
    printf ("%d\t%f\n", count_c, x);    
}
```

As it is you're only calling the convertTofahrenheit function once at the start of your program instead of for each celsius value.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there some way I can make the function better so I don't have to put the conversion in the loop?

Comment: The converted value is going to increase by 1.8 each time. So you could just convert the first value and then add 1.8 to the result each time through the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark if it solved your problem.